# Trouble returning response from asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, scope, closures

[Following this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DAcWT/) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), I wrote this bit of code:

```
var currentSlideCount = window.imgIds.length;

for (var i = 11; i < (currentSlideCount + 10); i++) {

// SET UP NEW SLIDE HTML
    var newSlide = '<li><img id="apod' + i + '" class="rounded-corners apod-image"></li>';
    $('#lightSlider').append(newSlide);
    window.imgIds.push('apod'+i);
    console.log(window.imgIds);

// GENERATE DATE
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - i);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

// GENERATE XML REQUEST
    function foo(callback) {
        var apodUrl = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?concept_tags=True&date=" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
        var apodXml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        apodXml.open('GET', apodUrl, true);
        apodXml.send(null);

        // WHEN REQUEST IS READY
        apodXml.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (apodXml.readyState==4 && apodXml.status==200) {
                var apodParse = JSON.parse(apodXml.responseText);
                callback(apodParse.url)
                console.log(apodParse.url);
            }
        }
    }

    foo(function(result) {
        var newSlideId = 'apod' + i;
        document.getElementById(newSlideId).src = result;
    });
```

Yet I'm still getting a **Cannot set property 'src' of null** console error on the img tag that was created long before its src attribute is being called on. And as far as I understand, I've set up the callback correctly. Why is this still not working?

Answer (score 3):

First, you are declaring the function `foo` in a loop. While this is not leading to an error, it's bad practice. The function should be declared outside of the loop.

Second, the callback function passed into `foo` is invoked **asynchronously** (i.e., via AJAX). The variable `i` is assigned a value in the **parent scope** of the callback function and **in a loop**. The loop will have finished executing by the time the callback is invoked. When the callback is invoked, it will look **up the scope chain** to find the value of `i` and it will find `i` declared in the loop. `i` will be equal to the final value in the loop for which the loop conditional `i < (currentSlideCount + 10)` evaluates false and does not continue.

While this may be hard to follow, you can see what I mean by adding `alert(i);` to the callback function:

```
 foo(function(result) {
    alert(i);
    var newSlideId = 'apod' + i;
    document.getElementById(newSlideId).src = result;
 });
```

You may be surprised to see that the alert will always display the same value for `i`.

To solve this problem, you need to use an immediately executing function to create a new scope where `i` is passed by value as the proper value you want.

Change this:

```
foo(function(result) {
    var newSlideId = 'apod' + i;
    document.getElementById(newSlideId).src = result;
});
```

To this:

```
foo(
    (function(i) {
        return function(result) {
            var newSlideId = 'apod' + i;
            document.getElementById(newSlideId).src = result;
        }
    })(i)
);
```

In JavaScript, scope is delineated at the **function level**. By using an immediately executing function, you are adding a new scope where `i` has been passed by value for the current iteration of the loop.

Variable scoping in JavaScript can be tricky to understand and your question hits right at one of the more complex scenarios. You may find it useful to review some [other explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) of scoping in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense. Thank you for explaining. Scope has been one of the most frustrating things about learning js. On that same note, can you explain how I would declare the function NOT inside a loop? Surely this would bring about other scope issues?

Comment: @JohnDoe You would just cut the `function foo { .... }` portion of your code and paste it at the top of your code sample. The scope of the function would not change. Scope is delineated at the function-level so moving it outside of the loop makes no difference in regards to scope. Right now, with the function declared inside the loop, you are declaring the same function over and over with every loop iteration -- that's not good for the performance of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems there:

1. You're using a function declaration inside a control structure. You can't do that, it's invalid; some browsers will try to rewrite it for you as a function expression, but others will not. Function declarations are only valid at the top level of a scope, outside of all control structures. E.g., at global scope or at the top level of a function.
2. More importantly, the callback you're passing to `foo` has an **enduring reference** to the `i` variable, not a copy of it as of when the function was created. So they all see `i` as it is when they run, later, at the **end** of the loop.

Move your `foo` function out of the control structure, and ideally parameterize it, in particular passing it the `i` value that the callback should use. E.g.:

```
var currentSlideCount = window.imgIds.length;

for (var i = 11; i < (currentSlideCount + 10); i++) {

    // SET UP NEW SLIDE HTML
    var newSlide = '<li><img id="apod' + i + '" class="rounded-corners apod-image"></li>';
    $('#lightSlider').append(newSlide);
    window.imgIds.push('apod' + i);
    console.log(window.imgIds);

    // GENERATE DATE
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - i);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

    foo(year, month, day, i, function(result, index) {
        var newSlideId = 'apod' + index;
        document.getElementById(newSlideId).src = result;
    });
}

// GENERATE XML REQUEST
function foo(year, month, day, index, callback) {
    var apodUrl = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?concept_tags=True&date=" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    var apodXml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    apodXml.open('GET', apodUrl, true);
    apodXml.send(null);

    // WHEN REQUEST IS READY
    apodXml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (apodXml.readyState == 4 && apodXml.status == 200) {
            var apodParse = JSON.parse(apodXml.responseText);
            callback(apodParse.url, index)
            console.log(apodParse.url, index);
        }
    }
}
```